# login error when nebula studio want to connect nebula graph docker instance

Tags: nebula-graph, nebula-studio

I have nebula graph instances as docker-machine and those worked as well.

I want to connect via nebula graph studio Version：v3.5.0 to my instance

[image: nebula graph studio]

there are 2 ways:

```
 1- using graphd:[port] like this graphd:9669

 2- using ip:port like this: 172.xx.xx.11:9669
```

but today i have error:

my error message is:

> ErrBadRequest::dial tcp 172.xx.xx.11:9669: connect: no route to host

Answer (score 1):

if you use IntelliJ please follow these steps:

[image: intellij api default]

1. click on the services tab
2. click on docker
3. click api_default

add your machine to that network then click ok

[image: connect network intellij docker]

then click connect

finally try use: graphd:9669 to connect to your nebula

Comment: the root cause is in the host:port, the host part should be accessible by the backend of the studio container :)